# Java: In what order are the methods called in an Applet?

Tags: java, applet

Of all these methods what's being run and in what order??
I guess the first question to ask is whats being run first?

**And why does th.start() start run()?**

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BallApplet extends Applet implements Runnable {
    int x_pos = 10;
    int y_pos = 100;
    int radius = 20;

    private Image dbImage;
    private Graphics dbG;

    public void init() {
        // setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread th = new Thread (this);
        th.start();
    }
    public void stop() {}
    public void destroy() {}

    public void run() {
        // 20 second delay per frame refresh (animation doesn't
        // need to be perfectly continuous)     
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

        while (true) {
            x_pos++;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Caught!");
            }
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }
    }
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        // implements double buffering
        // drawing on doublebufferImage, note the dbG=dbImage.getGraphics(), so everything dbG.whatever() is
        //      drawing on the Image's graphics which is later drawn with g.drawImage()

        // initialize buffer
        if (dbImage == null) {
            dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            dbG = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        // clear screen in background
        dbG.setColor(getBackground());  // gets background color
        dbG.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        // draw elements in background
        dbG.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbG);

        // draw image on the screen
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this); 
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x_pos-radius, y_pos-radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear of what is the purpose of pasting code here?

Comment: the Thread was created with "this", which is an object that implements the "Runnable" interface.  Thread.start() is _defined_ to create a new execution thread and then invoke the run() method on the original object.

Comment: I don’t want to be rude but could you please get yourself some beginner’s tutorial or book or something? All the questions you asked (and probably also the next couple ones you will ask) are answered there.

Comment: @Bombe, what's wrong with koldfyre asking newbie Java questions on stackoverflow? Stackoverflow can be the beginner's tutorial or book or something once it answers all of newbie Java questions, and that could be useful for the next newbie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init()` and `start()` methods are invoked first.

That in turn creates a `Thread` and starts that thread, which causes this class's `run()` method to be invoked.

The `paint()` method is invoked by Swing independently in the GUI event handling thread, if Swing detects that the applet needs to be redrawn.

I note that the class's main `run()` method also repeatedly calls `repaint()`.  That explicitly tells the GUI thread to invoke `update()`.

Answer (score 3):

The browser or Applet viewer first calls

- init() method to inform this applet that it has been loaded into the system.
- then after init start() method gets called. For more see the Applet class docs.
- Inside start() method there is a call to th.start(). That means start() the thread execution
- That will cause the run() to get invoked

Answer (score 3):

From the [Life Cycle of an Applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) section of [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html), the `Applet`'s following methods are called in order:

1. `init()`
2. `start()`
3. `stop()`
4. `destroy()`

In addition, the code implements the [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface, so the `BallApplet`'s `run()` method is also executed after a new `Thread` (here, called `th`) is run by calling the `th.start()` method. (Calling the `Thread.start()` method starts a new thread and calls its `run()` method.)

The [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) section from The Java Tutorials has more information on `Runnable` and `Thread` and how threads are started in Java.

The `run()` method contains a call to `repaint()`, and this is an app-triggered update, it will call the `BallApplet`'s `update(Graphics g)` method. In addition, the system-triggered repaint will trigger the `paint(Graphics g)` method.

For more information about repainting in AWT, refer to [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html). For information on system- and app-triggered painting, see the section on [System-Triggered vs. App-Triggered Painting](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#triggers).

Answer (score 0):

See [Thread.start()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()).

```
public void start()
```

> Causes this thread to begin execution;
>   the Java Virtual Machine calls the `run`
>   method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are
>   running concurrently: the current
>   thread (which returns from the call to
>   the start method) and the other thread
>   (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread
>   more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it
>   has completed execution.