# Java applet wont show image

Tags: java, image, loops, applet

I was trying to program my first Java applet and shortly after I started, I already have 2 problems.

1. The images won't show
2. Whenever I use the while-loop, which is converted into a comment in the following code, the applet won't do anything after initialising and won't react, too.

I already searched for the problem, but I can't find anything.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class start extends JApplet implements Runnable{


    public boolean pause = false;

    public Image bg;
    public Image back;
    public Image ground;
    public Image front;

    public void init(){

        setSize(800, 450);
        bg = getImage(getCodeBase(),"res/bg.PNG");      
        back = getImage(getCodeBase(),"res/back.PNG");
        ground = getImage(getCodeBase(),"res/ground.PNG");
        front = getImage(getCodeBase(),"res/front.PNG");
    }

    public void start(){
        Thread game = new Thread();
        game.start();
        run();
    }

    public void stop(){
    }

    public void destroy(){

    }

    public void run(){
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

//      while(!pause){
//          repaint();
//          
//          try{
//              Thread.sleep(25);
//          }catch(InterruptedException e){
//              
//          }

//      }

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }



    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(bg, 10, 10, this);
        g.drawImage(back, 10, 10, this);
        g.drawImage(ground, 10, 10, this);
        g.drawImage(front, 10, 10, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to make an entire new thread like that but I could be wrong. Maybe its drawing to the wrong thread?

Comment: 1) Are the images located in the `res` folder relative to the codebase? 2) You're painting over each image - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're trying to do what the example in here: [Java: In what order are the methods called in an Applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385824/java-in-what-order-are-the-methods-called-in-an-applet) does, if you note, the constructor of Thread used have reference to `this` and by the way, you don't need to call `run` yourself as this is part of the Thread class.